# USB3.0 to USB C cable doesn't work when plugged directly into USB C port, but does work when connected through hub

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, mouse

I have a 2023 M2 MacBook Pro, with an Anker USB-C hub. I also have a USB 3.0 Switch, that I use to switch my keyboard/mouse between my MacBook and my PC.

When I plug a USB-3 to USB-C cable directly into my MacBook, nothing happens; sometimes my mouse will light up, but the MacBook doesn't see it. The USB-3 to USB-C is male on both ends.

However, if I plug in the same USB-3 to USB-C cable into the Anker USB-C hub, everything works as expected. Is there any way that I can use the USB-C cable directly, without having to use the hub?

Basically, right now my set up looks like this:

`Mouse` --USB-A Cable--> `USB Switch` --USB-3 to USB-C--> `Anker Hub` --USB-C--> `MacBook`

But I want it to look like this:

`Mouse` --USB Cable--> `USB Switch` --USB-3 to USB-C--> `MacBook`

Note that the USB3 to USBC cable that I'm using did not come with the USB switch; its a separate cable that I had lying around.

These are the items in question.

- [Anker 555 USB-C Hub (8-in-1)](https://www.anker.com/products/a8383)
  [image]
- [ABLEWE 3.0 USB Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MBXMZLV)
  [image]

Comment: There's a lot of cheap USB switches on the market that violate the USB spec, they usually sell for low prices from popular online retailers.  One common violation of the USB spec is using USB-A ports as inputs, meaning that if the user puts in any cable other than the one included with the switch to connect anything then things go poorly.  The switch works with their own cable because the cable is also violating the spec, a kind of two wrongs make a right.  It is possible the hub is also doing something it should not.  I speculate because of a lack of details, such as port type and gender.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I updated the question with the links to the switch and the hub

Comment: @MacGuffin I updated the question, but the USB3 to USBC cable did not come with the switch; it was a separate cable that I had lying around. The switch cable is a male USBA to a male USBA cable. Also, since the cable works when plugged into Anker hub, but not the port directly, I suspect the issue is with the laptop port.

Comment: The USB-3 to USB-C is male on both ends

Answer (score 1):

The USB switch violates the USB specification by using USB-A ports as inputs, and by doing this they are putting at risk of damage anything connected to these ports. There is no fixing this, not in any way that makes any financial sense. The switch was built broken by not playing by the very simple rules set out in the USB spec.

Unplug everything from this switch and never attach another device again. This is a fire hazard. Connecting USB-A to USB-A is generally bad.  There are some exceptions to this rule but none of them involve connecting a computer to a USB switch.

The problem is the switch and the cables that came with it.  They took the cheap path than the correct one. Now you have cables and devices that could potentially cause damage to your electronics if not used carefully.

Again, there are cases where USB-A ports can be used safely for inputs but these are rare and they never transfer power. Power is to to flow out of USB-A ports, never flow in.  USB-A jacks or plugs are to sink power, never to supply it. If there's two devices supplying power by USB-A getting connected to each other then chance are high that permanent damage wall happen to one or both devices.

The best fix here is to be rid of the out-of-spec USB switch and start over. Trying to get this broken piece of kit working as intended is going to be more trouble than it is worth.

*Edit to add:  USB devices will either **source** power or they will **sink** power, they never **sync** power.  USB will **synch** data, as in "synchronize" that data but not "sink" data, unless the intent is to destroy it.  To send power or energy out is to be a *source*, and to the the one receiving that energy or power is to be the the sink.  If there is doubt on the terminology than refer to the USB specification or avoid any written commentary on the matter.*

Comment: Just for clarification to the OP -- and the switch takes in the not-to-spec signal from the USB-A's, and converts it into a valid USB signal to send to the computer.

Comment: I don't understand how the switch can be the problem; the mouse works when connected through the switch and the anker hub, it only fails when the switch is plugged directly into the Macbook. Also, if this is a safety concern, what should I be looking for in a replacement?

Comment: " I don't understand how the switch can be the problem; the mouse works when connected through the switch and the anker hub, it only fails when the switch is plugged directly into the Macbook. "  It is quite possible the MacBook USB ports have been damaged, no longer supplying power because the internal fuses have been blown by lugging in a dodgy USB switch.  The mouse works through the hub because the hub is now supplying power.  I suspect your cheap USB switch broke your MacBook.  Stop playing with this switch before you break more things.